# Wrapping the script line in travis.yml

Tags: node.js, npm, yaml, travis-ci

I have this .travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '9'
  - '8'
  - '7'
  - '6'
env:
  - CXX=g++-4.8
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-4.8

before_install: 'if [[ `npm -v` != 4* ]]; then npm i -g npm@4; fi'

install:
  - npm install --silent --no-optional > /dev/null 2>&1

script: 'rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install istanbul --silent > /dev/null 2>&1 && \
npm link -f --silent > /dev/null 2>&1 && npm link suman -f --silent  > /dev/null 2>&1 && \
suman test/src/dev/node/injection.test.js'
```

I am guessing that the script line is improperly formatted. I get this error on Travis:

```
The command "rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install istanbul --silent > /dev/null 2>&1 && \ npm link -f --silent > /dev/null 2>&1 && npm link suman -f --silent  > /dev/null 2>&1 && \ suman test/src/dev/node/injection.test.js" exited with 127.
```

Does anyone know that script command is formatted properly? I cannot figured it out.

Comment: I added spaces/newlines between before_install, install and script, not sure if that was a bad idea or not

Answer (score 4):

Looks like YAML conversion is biting you, and the newlines and `\` are treated differently than you are assuming. You can put in uninterpreted multiline block by starting it with a `|`. In case you are interested, check this for details: http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Block

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '9'
  - '8'
  - '7'
  - '6'
env:
  - CXX=g++-4.8
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-4.8

before_install: 'if [[ `npm -v` != 4* ]]; then npm i -g npm@4; fi'

install:
  - npm install --silent --no-optional > /dev/null 2>&1

script: |
    rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install istanbul --silent > /dev/null 2>&1 && \
    npm link -f --silent > /dev/null 2>&1 && npm link suman -f --silent  > /dev/null 2>&1 && \
    suman test/src/dev/node/injection.test.js
```

Comment: so the pipe symbol | tells yaml to interpret it as multiline?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the .travis.yml file in the OP was wrong ( I don't know exactly why), because when I changed it to:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '9'
  - '8'
  - '7'
  - '6'
env:
  - CXX=g++-4.8
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-4.8

before_install: 'if [[ `npm -v` != 4* ]]; then npm i -g npm@4; fi'
install:
  - 'npm install --silent --no-optional > /dev/null 2>&1'
script: 'rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install istanbul --silent > /dev/null 2>&1 && npm link -f --silent > /dev/null 2>&1 && npm link suman -f --silent  > /dev/null 2>&1 && suman test/src/dev/node/injection.test.js'
after_script: 'npm install -g coveralls && cat coverage/lcov.info | coveralls'
notifications:
  email: false
```

Now it's working again.